# How to download webpage from a particular folder using wget?

Tags: wget

I use wget to download webpages from websites but it downloads the whole website instead of downloading a specific folder on the website, even if I specify the particular path.For example,

```
wget -r www.example.com/subfolder/
```

Using the above command, downloads all the pages from the website instead of downloading the pages from /subfolder.

Answer (score 3):

The `wget` help shows the following option:

```
  -np, --no-parent                 don't ascend to the parent directory.
```

By default, there are likely links from the subfolder to the site home page, which wget normally follows.

Comment: It downloads only the index file in the folder, not all the files.

Comment: Are you continuing to use the `-r` option as well?

Comment: No, you need to specify *both* flags. `wget -r -np www.example.com/subfolder/`.

Comment: I tried all possible combinations of `-r` and `-np` , still it downloads only the index file.

Comment: Maybe there aren't any links to subfolders in that index file. It's hard to say for sure without a real site to look at.